# How we can assign value to the model fields inside a traits using foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is my model with protected `$uuidColumns=['event_uuid','space_uuid];`.

I want to Assign UUID to each field present inside `$uuidColumns` automatically.

My Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\UsesUuid;
use App\Traits\Uuids;

class EventSpace extends Model
{
    use Uuids;
    use UsesUuid;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'event_space';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'space_uuid';
    protected $casts = ['opening_hours' => 'array'];
    protected $uuidColumns = ['event_uuid'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'space_uuid',
        'space_name',
        'space_short_name',
        'space_mood',
        'max_capacity',
        'space_image_url',
        'space_icon_url',
        'is_vip_space',
        'opening_hours',
        'event_uuid',
        'tags'
    ];
}
```

My Trait:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

trait Uuids
{
    protected static function bootUuids()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $Uuid = $model->uuidColumns;
            foreach ($model->uuidColumns as $values) {
                $model->uuidColumns = Uuid::uuid1()->toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to generate UUID's whenever you create a new model and automatically assign them to the columns that you added in the `$uuidColumns` property.

The following should work inside your trait:

```
protected static function bootUuids()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        foreach ($model->uuidColumns as $column) {
            $model->{$column} = Uuid::uuid1()->toString();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use boot() instead of bootUuids()

```
protected static function boot() {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            foreach ($model->uuidColumns as $values) {
                $model->attributes[$values]= Uuid::uuid1()->toString();
            }
            
        });
    }
```

Comment: Here I have used bootUuids because I have two traits in Traits folder. One is boot and another is bootUuids. If change name from bootUuids to something else. Its not working then.